# The dot operand does not show methods

Tags: python, pycharm, networkx

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for coding in Python. Recently, I downloaded a library called `NetworkX` to use it for my project sake. It is successfully installed in the path `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package` by default (I run Ubuntu). It went fine when I import it, however the dot operand does not effectively showing me the classes and methods when using it !!!

I did the following

```
import networkx as nx

def graph():
  nx.    # dot operand is not working!!
```

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: If you absolutely have to use an IDE, I'd recommend PyCharm.

Comment: I will try it now. Thank you for your recommendation

Comment: Still same problem :(

Comment: @gragas PyCharm *is* Intellij IDEA with custom plugins for Python

Comment: I doubt if this will be helpful but this doesn't work when power saver mode is on.  Is this happening for all modules?